# What does "self.included(base)" mean in a module?

Tags: ruby

I see this pattern a lot:

```
module Article::Score

    def self.included(base)
        base.send :extend, ClassMethods
        base.send :include, InstanceMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
    ...
    end

    module InstanceMethods
    ...
    end
end
```

Then in the article model, I see this

```
class Article
   include Article::Score
   ...
end
```

so my guess is that "base" probably refers to the article class and we're just including the instance methods and extending the class methods.  But can someone explain the snippet "self.included(base)" and give an overview of what's going on there?

Comment: 'included' is one Ruby's several 'callback' (aka 'hook') methods.  You'll need to add these to your arsenal, not just admire their use by the clever ones. Another is '[inherited](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited)', something every parent needs: notification that it has another child to look after.  In his book, "Eloquent Ruby" (p. 249), Russ Olsen gives the example of a DocumentReader class, with one subclass for each type of document (text, XML, YAML,..).  By using `inherited`, no change is need to the parent's code when a new child is born (or leaves home).

Comment: The relevant page in the spec (for Ruby 2.7.0) is here: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included. The argument (which needn't be called `base`) is the module/class in which the module is being included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The self.included function is called when the module is included. It allows methods to be executed in the context of the base (where the module is included).

Comment: But why include the include those modules in such a round-about way?